# How to set the roation center of MkAnnotationview custom image in IOS6 mapkit framework

Tags: rotation, mapkit, mkannotationview

Using mapkit framework I want to display a arrow and rotate it, depending on the viewing direction of the user.

My problem is that the rotation center is in the lower left corner of the image.

I read this article about setting the roation center of `MkAnnotationViews`:

[How to set the rotation center of an MKAnnotationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629940/how-to-set-the-rotation-center-of-an-mkannotationview/13009437#13009437)

They say I can use `annotationView.layer.anchorPoint` to set the rotation center of the view but starting IOS6 mapkit framework the `MkAnnotationView.layer` property seems to be read only and you can't access `annotationView.layer.anchorPoint` at all. I doesn't even compile.

Is there another way ?

Comment: The layer property hasn't changed.  What's the exact compiler error?  Did you add the QuartzCore framework and import it?

Comment: Oh. I added it to Xcode but i didn't call #import <QuartzCore/CoreAnimation.h> to use it. Many thanks for this hint. No Compiler error anymore. I will test it now and give feedback

Comment: It worked perfectly. Quite a stupid mistake on my side. Thank you